# Should we merge the 'import' and 'importing' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have both [import](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import) and [importing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importing) as separate tags (and no guidance for either).

My quick survey of them found two general use cases:

- Bringing some sort of game asset from one system to another. For instance importing a model from Blender into Unity. This seems to be the primary use.
- Technical programming problems involving `import` as keyword, build command or given as part of an error message.

Should we merge them and if so, what sort of guidance should be provided?
Are they meta-tags & should we remove them?

Comment: Did you notice different patterns in usage of those two? Are they really useful anyway? Can one be an expert in "importing"/what could be the resulting tagd description?

Comment: @Vaillancourt Not originally - I found the pair accidentally when I took the wrong tag off a question I was editing. When I typed it back in, the system offered both & I thought that was weird. I've since collected more info & added it to the post. The programming version seems like a meta-tag to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuke those tags.

And blocklist them.

If it's about the concept of `import`ing other files in python, then the question is likely one about code and should be asked on Stack Overflow.

If it's about importing assets, then the tag should be able to stand on it's own, and I don't see how someone could be an expert in "importing". There are too many ways to interpret what "importing" means so we won't be able to come up with a usage guide that will match what the average user thinks it's about.

---

As usual, removing a tag from questions implies re-reading each question and making sure it's properly tagged.

Comment: Sorry, seeing this late. I agree - I think anything relating to importing assets can fit under [tag:asset-workflow] just fine.

Comment: @DMGregory Ah, right; then that would be a tag to consider when editing the questions.

Comment: @DMGregory Not sure if this should be a seperate stand alone question: should 'import' (and maybe 'export') be made synonyms with 'asset-workflow'?

Comment: I don't think they're synonymous, since some asset-workflow questions are not about importing per se. I think import is superfluous, and depending on the context might be better served by asset-workflow, serialization, or other unrelated tags.